# Circuit design - usage of BOOT0 on STM32G474

Tags: stm32

I'm involved in a collaboration to develop a motor driver circuit based on the 48 pin [STM32G474](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/dm00431551-1799305.pdf) microcontroller. I'm using TIM8 timers to drive the PWM of a [DRV8323RH](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=26&gotoUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fds%2Fsymlink%2Fdrv8323r.pdf) chip.

My question is about the use of BOOT0 pin. My understanding of the BOOT0 pin is that when the BOOT0 pin is at a low level, the STM32G4 microcontroller boots from the User Flash memory. When the BOOT0 pin is at a high level, the nBOOT1 bit determines the boot mode.

Where I'm confused is that in a previous incarnation of the PCB we tied BOOT0 to ground, and programmed STM32G474 we use an st-link2 system, through the TCK and TMS pins. In this incarnation of the board we would prefer to use PB8-BOOT0 to send PWM to the driver chip.

If I am programming using the st-link2 system as before, will I still be able to program the STM32G4 if I tie the PB8-BOOT0 to PWM of the driver?

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is not only one `nBOOT1` bit for boot configuration on STM32G4 devices.

There are also `nBOOT0` and `nSWBOOT0` bits, which allow to use different boot options as well as describe the use of BOOT0 pin.

Table 5 in section "2.6.1 Boot configuration" on page 89 of [STM32G4 Series Reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00355726-stm32g4-series-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) shows, that there are such configuration that state on Reset of BOOT0 pin doesn't matter (you can even don't have any pull-up on it).

[image: Boot configuration]

And, actually, BOOT0 pin has nothing to do with programming the MCU with ST-Link. BOOT0 only allows you to select the memory area to start the program execution. You can program MCU with any boot configuration selected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as the Boot0 pin has a pull-down resistor so it is low when the MCU comes out of reset, it will boot to user program. It can be programmed via JTAG or SWD as usual.

Comment: Thank you but wont that mean I would not be able to use it to send PWM signals to the DRV chip?

Comment: No, it does not mean that.